# Grouping by month and year gives wrong answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table and inserted the values in my database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
  date DATE,
  total_rides INT
);

INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-01'), 985);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-02'), 801);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-03'), 1349);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-04'), 1562);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-05'), 1600);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-06'), 1606);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-07'), 1510);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-08'), 959);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-09'), 822);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-10'), 1321);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-11'), 1263);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-12'), 1162);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-13'), 1406);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-14'), 1421);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-15'), 1248);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-16'), 1204);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-17'), 1000);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-18'), 683);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-19'), 1650);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-20'), 1927);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-21'), 1543);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-22'), 981);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-23'), 986);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-24'), 1416);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-25'), 1985);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-26'), 506);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-27'), 431);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-28'), 1167);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-29'), 1098);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-30'), 1096);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-01-31'), 1501);

INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-01'), 1360);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-02'), 1526);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-03'), 1550);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-04'), 1708);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-05'), 1005);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-06'), 1623);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-07'), 1712);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-08'), 1530);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-09'), 1605);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-10'), 1538);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-11'), 1746);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-12'), 1472);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-13'), 1589);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-14'), 1913);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-15'), 1815);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-16'), 2115);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-17'), 2475);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-18'), 2927);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-19'), 1635);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-20'), 1812);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-21'), 1107);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-22'), 1450);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-23'), 1917);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-24'), 1807);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-25'), 1461);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-26'), 1969);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-27'), 2402);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2011-02-28'), 1446);

INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-01'), 2294);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-02'), 1951);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-03'), 2236);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-04'), 2368);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-05'), 3272);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-06'), 4098);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-07'), 4521);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-08'), 3425);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-09'), 2376);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-10'), 3598);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-11'), 2177);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-12'), 4097);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-13'), 3214);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-14'), 2493);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-15'), 2311);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-16'), 2298);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-17'), 2935);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-18'), 3376);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-19'), 3292);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-20'), 3163);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-21'), 1301);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-22'), 1977);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-23'), 2432);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-24'), 4339);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-25'), 4270);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-26'), 4075);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-27'), 3456);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-28'), 4023);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-29'), 3243);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-30'), 3624);
INSERT INTO TASK VALUES(('2012-01-31'), 4509);
```

I wanted to calculate the `average` daily number of shared bikes monthly and also `variance` of daily shared bikes for each month in two years and for that I wrote a query:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE) AS mon, YEAR(date) AS Yr, AVG(task.total_rides) AS Average, std(task.total_rides) AS stdev, VARIANCE(task.total_rides) AS Var
FROM task
GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(task.date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(task.date) AS VARCHAR(4));
```

and the output it gives me is:

```
mon  Yr        Average        stdev          Var
1    2,011    1231.9032     366.3764      134231.7003
2    2,011    2456.9322     973.6375      947969.9615
```

Only the first result for the month of Jan in 2011 is correct.

Instead of calculating the avg, std & variance of Feb 2011 & Jan 2012 separately and showing the output as:

**Expected output:**

```
mon  Yr        Average        stdev          Var
1    2,011    1231.9032     366.3764      134231.7003
2    2,011    1721.9643     391.3279      153137.5344
1    2,012    3120.7742     858.6585      737294.3684
```

It is combining all the values belonging to feb 2011 & jan 2012 together and then computing the avg, std & var.

Any idea what is the mistake I am doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing your `GROUP BY` portion to
`GROUP BY MONTH(DATE), YEAR(date)`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton. Can you explain why was my `GROUP BY` doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm actually surprised you were able to use your query without any errors (apart from unexpected output). SQL Server requires that "each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the <select> list must be included in the GROUP BY list". I'm not familiar with how MySQL handles this specific situation. In general, the `GROUP BY` clause partitions the table returned by your select query by splitting it into unique groups based on the columns you are aggregating by. In this case, you're aggregating on every unique combination of month and year.

Comment: @Junkrat Try adding your original group by expression to your select to see what you were actually grouping by; since mysql uses the `CONCAT` function for string concatenation, not the `+` operator, my guess is a meaningless int value. _Even if you had used CONCAT, tim's suggesting is still better as it is the least operations on the fields you are grouping on._

Comment: @tim If MySQL isn’t in proper strict mode and is older than 8 it notoriously wont care about grouping and columns being used without aggregates etc. It will happily return whatever random row it wants to when querying. It’s a well known problem that’s finally handled, too bad a lot of people use older version and don’t have proper settings.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I see that now that I'm looking at the documentation. Looks fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the grouping using the separate month and year parts or use proper syntax for concatenation:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(CAST(MONTH(task.date) AS VARCHAR(2)), '-', CAST(YEAR(task.date) AS VARCHAR(4)))
```

or

```
GROUP BY MONTH(task.date), YEAR(task.date)
```

The latter is preferred since it works with numeric data, uses the results you use (so it works with proper strict settings) and you don’t use the concatenated string anywhere otherwise.

The reason why your way doesn’t work is that `+` is not for concatenation strings. It’s for addition. And because MySQL assumes any string can be converted to a number it doesn’t cause an error. So your query calculated 2011+0+2 and  2012+0+1 to both be 2013 and grouped them together.

The way MySQL converts implicitly to numbers works by taking as many numeric characters from the beginning as possible. So ‘123abc’ is equal to 123 and ‘-‘ is zero since no numeric characters in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method as I mentioned in the comment is adding year and month to your `GROUP BY` separately:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS mon,
       YEAR(date) AS Yr,
       AVG(task.total_rides) AS Average,
       STD(task.total_rides) AS stdev,
       VARIANCE(task.total_rides) AS Var
FROM task
GROUP BY MONTH(date),
         YEAR(date);
```

Generally, you want to include every non-aggregated column in your `GROUP BY` clause. There are some exceptions you can get away with ([explained here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)), but it makes your code less readable and less portable to other DBMSs.